# Erlang List Comprehension of Cartesian Product

Tags: erlang, list-comprehension, cartesian-product

I'm learning Erlang and have come across/trying to understand list comprehension. I've discovered that you can make Cartesian products quite easily using it.

Basically I though of a deck of cards and that if you multiply the unique values by the number of suits, you will result will every possible combination - creating a full deck of cards. However, what if I wish to add the 2 jokers to the deck - but jokers do not belong to a suit. How do we solve that issue?

The code below is what I have so far and will output the possible combinations without the jokers.

```
CardValues = [ace, king, queen, jack, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2],
CardSuits =  [spades,hearts,clubs,diamonds],
CartesianList = [{X, Y} || X <- CardValues, Y <- CardSuits ],
io:format("\nCartesianList:~p\n",[CartesianList]).
```

Would there be a better way of achieving/how would you achieve this?
I expect the output for the jokers would be something like {joker, nosuit}
Thanks,
Snelly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to get it directly from a list comprehension, you may use filters:

```
CardValues = [joker,joker,ace, king, queen, jack, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2],
CardSuits =  [spades,hearts,clubs,diamonds,nosuit],
CartesianList = [{X, Y} || X <- CardValues, Y <- CardSuits, ((X == joker)andalso(Y==nosuit))orelse((X =/= joker)andalso(Y=/=nosuit)) ],
io:format("\nCartesianList:~p\n",[CartesianList]).
```

But it is really weird, artificial and inefficient, I would add them manually:

```
CardValues = [ace, king, queen, jack, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2],
CardSuits =  [spades,hearts,clubs,diamonds],
CartesianList = [{joker,nosuit},{joker,nosuit}|[{X, Y} || X <- CardValues, Y <- CardSuits ]]],
io:format("\nCartesianList:~p\n",[CartesianList]).
```

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of the first solution in my head. Although I agree with you saying that's a really weird way to go about things having looked at the second snippet. Thanks for your help, I think I'm finally comprehending comprehension :)